# SQL Developer - how to assess change to data model

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, sqldeveloper

I'm working with a schema I'm not familiar with and am trying to find out if there is a way to do a diff between the state of the data in the schema instance between transactions - does anyone know if there is a way to do it in SQL Developer? I want to know what tables were touched during a transaction.

I know you can do a diff between different DBs for the schema but not sure if you can do a diff between the data.

Comment: Not an answer... but you might be able to find something or get better responses on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, BlueGI I will try there if no luck here!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

You could use the **Schema Comparison Wizard of Oracle SQL Developer** through the
menu *Tools > Database Diff*. This option uses Oracle Change Management,
a payable option of the Oracle database, for which you need a license.

For a description with screenshots see the article
[Using the SQL Developer Diff Feature](https://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/using-sql-developer-diff-feature).

An alternative product is the costly
[dbForge Schema Compare for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/compare-bundle/).

For more information and review of the two products see the article
[Comparing Diffs Between Two Oracle Database Schemas](https://blog.devart.com/comparing-two-oracle-schemas-is-simple-now.html).

Comment: Cheers hayyrmc but I want to get a view of how the data has changed in the same database and the diff wizard needs separate instances. Maybe I just need to use some log tools.

Comment: For comparing data, the simplest might be to export the tables in some format that is easy to compare, such as `.csv`.